# C - Buffer on heap not lost after EXEC but saved on stack

Tags: c, pointers, overflow, heap-memory

I was studying stack buffer overflows and I saw something that made me think. First of all the operating system is **Damn Vulnerable Linux** with kernel **2.6.20** and **ASLR disabled**.

The fact is that I knew that when you call an exec function inside a C program, the memory in the heap and stack is zeroed and lost. But if I allocate a buffer in the heap (malloc) and then I pass a pointer to that buffer as argument to the program executed with the exec function, the data inside the buffer (in the heap) is saved on the stack. So at the end of the exec I have the buffer (that was in the heap before) in the stack.
In order to make it clearer here's an example:

```
Program: bingo

#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    int i;
    char *buffer=malloc(600);
    for (i=0;i<600;i++){
         buffer[i]='A';
    }
    buffer[600-1]=0;
    execl("./test","test",buffer,0);

    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

And test will be a simple program.

```
Program: test

#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
    printf("Hello world\n");        

    return 0;
}
```

Now if I debug the bingo program with GDB I can see that the content of buffer (all the As) that were put in the heap are actually copied on the stack during the execl function. So at the end of the execution of the program the heap is zeroed but the content of the buffer has been completely copied on the stack. My explanation is that this happens because this way the content of buffer will be made available to the executed program (test). I'd just like to know if this behaviour is normal.
My doubt was: when I call the execl function I actually pass a pointer as argument to the executed program (test). 'Cause buffer is a pointer. So my (probably stupid) question is: shouldn't only the pointer be passed to the executed program and not also the content pointed by the pointer?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason buffer is copied to the stack is that it is being passed as a parameter, argv[1] in ./test.   buffer is just a variable which references a memory location in bingo. Heap allocations do not persist when a process
exits.

Note: suppose buffer references `0xfff123` in the memory of the bingo process. That is a virtual (process-specific) address. `0xffff123` may not even be mapped into ./test.  So passing a pointer to `0xfff123` is not guaranteed to do what you think.

After `execl` is called successfully,  bingo then exits at that point, and all memory associated with the process is lost, and  `free(buffer)` never executes.

Answer: No. Process heap allocation does not persist across processes.  Shared memory objects are kernel persistent, the results of a `malloc` invocation are not.

I'm not sure where all of your confusion lies, but this is my best guess.

Relative addressing example:

Processes all have a `0x00000000` (on 32 bit) address.  IF the kernel mapped every process to the same physical address, each process would share `0x0000000`
This cannot physically happen.  The kernel changes the virtual address (the `0x0000000` ) to real physical address like `0x3535fffa`.   So my pointer in my process is "aimed at" `0x00000000` virtual but this is really `0x3535fffa`.

What this means is you cannot directly pass heap pointers between processes.  It won't work.  My pointer to `0x3535fffa` will be a different physical address from where your `0x3535fffa` used to reference.

execl is simply copying AAAAA's into your new buffer inside ./test memory, as you saw.

Comment: Here what I'm struggling with. buffer is a pointer and is passed as argument to execl. So the pointer is put on the stack. The executed program (test) should have just the pointer on the stack. What surprises me is that during the execution of execl the **content** referenced by the pointer is put on the stack. In fact when the test program is executed I can see all the As on the stack. I'm sorry for being so ignorant but I can't understand what is happening.

Comment: Oh.  What is happening:  the char ** argv array consists of pointers to data in the NEW process. argv[0] is the name "test", argv[1] is buffer.  In order for ./test to see the parameter argv[1]- that is now what this is - there has to be data for the pointer to be "aimed at".  Also note: if buffer pointed to the old process address, ./test would be out of luck.  All of bingo's heap has been removed and probably assigned to another process.  There is nothing there. Plus, pointers are virtual as I explained. 0x0000 does NOT refer to the same physical address in each process, the kernel routes it

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Now everything is clearer. Basically the content of buffer is "remapped" in the address space of the executed program. In this case the content is copied on the stack, so that it is available to the new program (through argv[1]). One last question: I've never found detailed info about this mechanism written in books I've read. Do you know any resources I can study where this specific mechanism (as for GNU/Linux operating systems) is explained in detail? Anyway thank you for your patience and support.

Comment: [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory)  explains address translation.  The manual page for execve or any of its related system calls tells you what happens to most process attributes during process creation.(man execl, execve...) See also Michael Kerrisk 'The Linux Programming Interface' the section on the exec family of calls.